# SQl 2000 Reporting Services and SQL 2005 Reporting Services side by side?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, sql-server-2000

Does anyone know if it is possible to install SQL 2000 Reporting Services Server side by side with SQL 2005 Reporting Services Server?

The Reports and ReportServer virual directories are both virtual directories in the default website and they use different .net frameworks. Is this even allowed? Do I need to create a new website to support one of the two engines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is YES.  You must keep the SQL Server 2000 version as the default instance, and the SQL Server 2005 version as a named instance.  Also,

> The virtual directories must be unique
>   for each report server and Report
>   Manager instance.
>
> You can use the same Web site for all
>   virtual directories. However, you
>   should create a separate application
>   pool for the SQL Server 2005 report
>   server and Report Manager
>   applications.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143520(SQL.90).aspx)